# How can I add another button that'll also scan the qrcode but post to a different URL

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Now, I have a button that will trigger the camera function to scan the

qrcode and then will post the result to the PHP script.

How can I **add another button** that'll also scan the qrcode but post to a

different URL.

I have tried to add another button but it kept posting to the same URL

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController,     
 QRCodeReaderViewControllerDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate{

     //scan
     @IBOutlet weak var previewView: QRCodeReaderView! {
     didSet {
      previewView.setupComponents(showCancelButton: false,     showSwitchCameraButton: false, showTorchButton: false, showOverlayView: true, reader: reader)
    }
    }



    }


    }
```

> //QR code reader

```
lazy var reader: QRCodeReader = QRCodeReader()
 lazy var readerVC: QRCodeReaderViewController = {
let builder = QRCodeReaderViewControllerBuilder {
  $0.reader          = QRCodeReader(metadataObjectTypes: [.qr], captureDevicePosition: .back)
  $0.showTorchButton = true

  $0.reader.stopScanningWhenCodeIsFound = false
}

return QRCodeReaderViewController(builder: builder)
 }()
```

> // MARK: - Actions

```
  private func checkScanPermissions() -> Bool {
   do {
  return try QRCodeReader.supportsMetadataObjectTypes()
   } catch let error as NSError {
  let alert: UIAlertController

  switch error.code {
  case -11852:
    alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "This app is not   authorized to use Back Camera.", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Setting", style: .default, handler: { (_) in
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let settingsURL = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
          UIApplication.shared.openURL(settingsURL)
        }
      }
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
  default:
    alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Reader not supported by the current device", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
  }

  present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

  return false
   }
   }
```

> //scan

```
   @IBAction func scanInModalAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
  guard checkScanPermissions() else { return }

readerVC.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
readerVC.delegate                = self

readerVC.completionBl ock = { (result: QRCodeReaderResult?) in
  if let result = result {
    print("Completion with result: \(result.value) of type \(result.metadataType)")
  }
}

present(readerVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  // MARK: - QRCodeReader Delegate Methods

 func reader(_ reader: QRCodeReaderViewController, didScanResult     result: QRCodeReaderResult){
    reader.stopScanning()

  dismiss(animated: true) { [weak self] in


    //device id

    let deviceUUID: String = (UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString)!

    //POST REQUEST start



    let myUrl2 = URL(string: ((self?.myString)! + "/testing00/attendance/scan.php"));



    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl2!)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string

    let postString = "imie=" + deviceUUID + "&qrcode=" + result.value

    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

        if error != nil
        {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        if let data = data {
            let string = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            print(string) //

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.outlet4.text = string
            }

        }


    }
    task.resume()

}

}



  func readerDidCancel(_ reader: QRCodeReaderViewController) {
   reader.stopScanning()

   dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
 }
```

Comment: Format the code properly. https://www.osehra.org/blog/any-fool-can-write-code-computer-can-understand-good-programmers-write-code-humans-can-understa